# Parse cloud code query not triggering success or error

Tags: swift, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have a parse cloud code function which i'm using to get some information from one of my classes called SourcesTopData as you can see in the picture below, this is being called in swift whenever the app launches.

[image: Classes Objects]

The issue i'm having is it seems like the query code i'm using to get this information isn't working. The function being used is below.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("myNews", function (request, response) {

    var newsJsonData = {
        "stories": []
    };

    // Check the params and get the range
    if (parseInt(request.params.myoffset) === 0) {

        endIndex = 5;

    } else {
        startIndex = request.params.myoffset;
        endIndex = startIndex + 5;
    }



    var promises = _.each(request.params.keys, function (news_api_key) {

        if (request.params.Type == "Top") {



            var query = new Parse.Query("SourceTopData");
            query.equalTo("guid", news_api_key);

            console.log("The api key is " + news_api_key);

            query.find({

                success: function (results) {

                    console.log("The results are");
                    console.log("The icon name is  " + results[0].get("icon") + " The source name is " + results[0].get("source") + " The url id is " + results[0].get("guid_url"));

                },
                error: function () {

                    console.log("FAIL");
                    success = false;

                    response.error("Query lookup failed");
                }
            });

        }
    });


    Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function () {

        response.success(newsJsonData);

    }, function () {
        response.error("No stories");
    });

});
```

The line where i am trying to log the columns under the `console.log("The results are");` is printing nothing. After moving the logging i've found that the code isn't going into the success or the fail in the query find but i can't seems to figure out why this is since looking at the doc i've set up the `Parse.Query` properly.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything for the promises to handle:

```
return query.find({
```

Comment: It's still not logging the values inside of the success.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesnt log anything inside the IF there is probably something wrong with that if

try logging this before you enter the if and you will see what is inside

```
console.log("type: " + request.params.Type);
```

Also if you want to log all the results you have to put them in FOR cycle

`var query = new Parse.Query("SourceTopData");
    query.equalTo("guid", news_api_key);
    query.find({
      success: function(results) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            console.log("The icon name is  " + results[i].get("icon"));
        };
        console.log("Total results: " + results.length);
      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log("FAIL error: " + error);
      }
    });`

Comment: Still the same thing mate. It's not logging anything in the success or the error at all.